# Intel MKL cblas_dgemm documention error?

Tags: blas, intel-mkl

This link is the manual of `MKL`,

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/index.htm,

and This link is the example of `cblas_dgemm`,

http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?cmd=getdoc&coll=0650&db=man&fname=3%20INTRO_CBLAS

In the manual, Under `RowMajor`, `NoTransA` and `NoTransB` he says `lda` is the `rows(A)`,`ldb` is the `rows(B)`, `ldc` is the `rows(C)`,
**But,**
In the example,

```
    float a[10][20], b[20][30], c[10][30];
    cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 10, 30,
             20, 1.0f, a, 20, b, 30, 0.0f, c, 30);
```

the `lda` and `ldb` and `ldc` is the `cols(a)` , `cols(b)` , `cols(c)`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example your showed is correct. For row-major matrix without padding byte, leading dimension is equal to the number of columns.

I can't find `lda is the rows(A)` in MKL doc, could you provide a traceable link instead?

PS: You may want to change to the latest version of MKL docs.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-documentation

Comment: Hi, Eric. Please check this link:http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-97718E5C-6E0A-44F0-B2B1-A551F0F164B2.htm#GUID-97718E5C-6E0A-44F0-B2B1-A551F0F164B2, he says `lda
INTEGER. Specifies the leading dimension of a as declared in the calling (sub)program. When transa = 'N' or 'n', then lda must be at least max(1, m), otherwise lda must be at least max(1, k).`

Comment: That's the parameter description for fortran, which uses col-major matrices.